# Node - Limit data sent back as virtual object

Tags: node.js, mongoose

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const constants = require('../utils/constants')

const eventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    eventStatus : {
        type : Number,
        required : [true, constants.params_missing]
    },
    .
    .
    .
    creatorId : {
        type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required : true,
        ref : 'User'
    }
}, {
    timestamps : true
})

eventSchema.set('toObject', { virtuals: true })

eventSchema.virtual('creator', {
    ref : 'User',
    localField : 'creatorId',
    foreignField: '_id'
})

eventSchema.methods.toJSON = function() {

    const eventObject = this.toObject()
    delete eventObject.creatorId
    delete eventObject.__v
    delete eventObject.createdAt
    delete eventObject.updatedAt
    return eventObject
}

const Event = mongoose.model('Event', eventSchema)
module.exports = Event
```

Now when the request is hit, what i do is:

```
const event = new Event(params)
await event.save()
await event.populate('creator').execPopulate()
res.send({event})
```

Now this is working as expected and i'm getting the entire `user` object inside the virtual property. What i would like to do is limit the amount of data i receive like maybe only send back 2-3 properties from the entire `user` object. How do i go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the official [documentation on field selection](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#field-selection) should also work on virtual fields:

```
Story.
 findOne({ title: /casino royale/i }).
 populate('author', 'name'). // only return the Persons name
 exec(function (err, story) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);

  console.log('The author is %s', story.author.name);
  // prints "The author is Ian Fleming"

  console.log('The authors age is %s', story.author.age);
  // prints "The authors age is null'
});
```

Alternatively use the path-syntax as described in this comment by @vkarpov15:
https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4680#issuecomment-260160068

```
Book.findOne({})
 .populate({
   path: 'creator', 
   options: { select: { name: 1, age: 1 } } 
}).execPopulate()
```